# declined to override a veto - is that a Yes or a No?

Tags: negation, double-negation

The full sentence from the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/12/04/nyregion/chris-christie-veto-of-gun-control-bill-is-upheld-as-assembly-halts-override.html) reads:

> One day after a mass shooting in California left 14 people dead, Republican lawmakers in New Jersey declined on Thursday to override Gov. Chris Christie’s veto of a gun-control bill they had unanimously supported in June.

I can't tell... **was the law passed or not?**

Comment: Why is this tagged double-negation? I can’t see it. There isn’t even a single  negative here.

Comment: words like **decline**,  **veto**  and **override** have some negative connotations.

Answer (score 4):

The State legislature unanimously supported a bill, and it should have become law.

The Governor's veto stopped the bill becoming law.

If lawmakers had overridden the veto, the bill would have become law.

They declined to override it; the veto stands, and the bill did not become law.

The bill was **passed** but vetoed, and the veto was confirmed. The bill **did not become law.**

Comment: Was the veto *confirmed* or *not overturned*? Article V Section I Paragraph 14 of the [New Jersey constitution](http://www.njleg.state.nj.us/lawsconstitution/constitution.asp) hardly helps.

Comment: I'm not bothered about the constitutional niceties. I wanted a synonym for "not overridden", and "confirmed" means the **effect** is the same.

Comment: Every week, the online New York Times runs a column called After Deadline, which lists the various grammatical and stylistic errors that got through uncaught.  I saw that paragraph today and thought to myself that this paragraph will be in next week's edition.